# Can others see the reports generated by allure-serve?

Tags: pytest, allure

when I try to serve allure reports by using allure-serve it generates a URL of format

http://192.168.X.XXX:553XX/index.html

where 192.168.X.XXX:553XX is probably my ipaddress:portnumber.

Will this be accessible to users on the same network ? If not, How to make this report accessible to others on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

`allure serve` command is very useful to take a look at your reports but if you what to host your reports the best way is to generate reports using `allure generate` and after that to serve them using nginx.

`allure generate --clean <path to results> -o <path to reports>` will generate all static files required for hosting.

[Here is a good tutorial how to serve static files using nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/)